# Load .txt files in Pandas DataFrame with separator line in between text.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, separator

I have text file which contains text like this:

```
--------------------------------
I hate apples and love oranges.
He likes to ride bike.
--------------------------------

--------------------------------
He is a man of honour. 
She loves to travel.
--------------------------------
```

I want to load this txt file in pandas dataframe and each row containing the content only between the separator. For e.g:

Row 1 should be like: 
    I hate apples and love oranges.
    He likes to ride bike.

Row 2 should be like:
He is a man of honour. 
She loves to travel.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to pre-process the text.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
res = []
temp = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        val = line.strip()
        if val:        
            if not val.startswith("-"):
                temp.append(val)
            else:
                if temp:
                    res.append(" ".join(temp))
                    temp = []

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Test"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                                Test
0  I hate apples and love oranges. He likes to ri...
1        He is a man of honour. She loves to travel.
```